# Codigo para tabular un xml

Tags: javascript, xml

necesito hacer un código para poder meter tabulaciones a un xml en un js por que me lo envían en una linea y necesito que esté en forma de árbol para que mi sistema lo interprete.

Es decir me envían un xml con una linea con diferentes etiquetas y necesito que el js lo recoga, le meta las tabulaciones bien en plan vkbeautify y me lo guarde.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor Christian muestra lo que has intentado, y el error que tienes, StackOverflow no es una página donde se resuelvan ejercicios o tareas.

Answer (score -1):

Este código hace lo que necesitas formatear el xml mono linea y lo muestra multilinea
utiliza expresiones regulares para poder formatear con la correcta indentación

la fuente del código es [link](https://gist.github.com/sente/1083506/d2834134cd070dbcc08bf42ee27dabb746a1c54d)

```js
function formatXml(xml) {
    var formatted = '';
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
    var pad = 0;
    jQuery.each(xml.split('\r\n'), function(index, node) {
        var indent = 0;
        if (node.match( /.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/ )) {
            indent = 0;
        } else if (node.match( /^<\/\w/ )) {
            if (pad != 0) {
                pad -= 1;
            }
        } else if (node.match( /^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/ )) {
            indent = 1;
        } else {
            indent = 0;
        }

        var padding = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
            padding += '  ';
        }

        formatted += padding + node + '\r\n';
        pad += indent;
    });

    return formatted;
}


xml_raw = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><employees><employee><id>1</id><firstName>Scarlett</firstName><lastName>Johansson</lastName><photo>http://si.wsj.net/public/resources/images/BN-BY925_mag041_OZ_20140318165119.jpg</photo></employee><employee><id>2</id><firstName>Chris</firstName><lastName>Evans</lastName><photo>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/605082381528096769/gt_sJRot.png</photo></employee><employee><id>3</id><firstName>Jeremy</firstName><lastName>Renner</lastName><photo>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/603945839795412992/XTssKbRC.jpg</photo></employee></employees>';

xml_formatted = formatXml(xml_raw);

xml_escaped = xml_formatted.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/\n/g,'<br />');

var mydiv = document.createElement('div');

mydiv.innerHTML = xml_escaped;

document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header"></h1>
```

Comment: OK gracias, pero el siguiente script <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="header"></h1> ¿va en otro archivo?

Comment: va en el html donde ejecutes  esta funcionalidad es una libreria jquery link -> https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/pasos-para-ejecutar-jquery.html
 seria recomendable que para que marcaras la respuesta como correcta si te ha solucionado las dudas